# Get AudioRecord (Samsung Young) null in android

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I want to capture the audio so I am using the AudioRecord. But I'm getting null in the AudioRecord. Please help me so that it work in all the phones.

```
private static int[] mSampleRates = new int[] { 44100, 44056, 47250, 48000, 22050, 16000, 11025, 8000 };


public AudioRecord findAudioRecord() {
    for (int rate : mSampleRates) {
        for (short audioFormat : new short[] { AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT }) {
            for (short channelConfig : new short[] { AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO }) {
                try {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Attempting rate " + rate + "Hz, bits: " + audioFormat + ", channel: "
                            + channelConfig);
                    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, channelConfig, audioFormat);

                    if (bufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                        // check if we can instantiate and have a success
                        AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.DEFAULT, rate, channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize);

                        if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)
                            return recorder;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, rate + "Exception, keep trying.",e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Comment: Try some other AudioSources, like `MIC`.

Comment: I tried like MIC but still null.. I tried with this `AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, rate, channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize);`  This condition false `if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)`

Answer (score 0):

do you have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>
```

in your manifest?